# How to generate boolean buildConfigField WITHOUT final attribute

Tags: android, gradle

Inside an Android project with multiple build variants, I define a build FLAG inside the build.gradle file like this:

**debug**
*buildConfigField "boolean", "FLAG", "false"*

**release**
*buildConfigField "boolean", "FLAG", "true"*

This will be available inside the BuildConfig.java in this format:
*public static final boolean FLAG = true; / false;*

For testing purposes, I would like to have the option, only for the debug build, to change the value to test different scenarios.
But, being a final member, I cannot do it.

Is it possible to generate that boolean member without the **final** attribute for a specific build variant?
I was thinking of create a gradle task that would modify the content of the BuildConfig class before building the apk. Is this possible?

Comment: "Is it possible to generate that boolean member without the final attribute for a specific build variant?" -- not directly. "I was thinking of create a gradle task that would modify the content of the BuildConfig class before building the apk. Is this possible?" -- in principle, sure. Parsing a Java class is icky, and getting your task hooked into the build at the appropriate point may be tricky. I suggest that your tests not rely directly upon the `BuildConfig` field, but that you do something else that allows for modification (e.g., dependency injection, mocking).

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I am aware of the DI alternative. I am looking also to investigate solutions to the current way of using the project. Any ideas on how to accomplish it?